# how to prevent loss of image quality on ios platform on unity

Tags: ios, image, unity-game-engine, game-engine, texture2d

I am making an ios game using unity3d 4.3 version.I have an image made with photoshop with various gradient effect on it.When I try to use it on unity game engine on ios platform,its quality is just wasted.But it is ok on windows platform.I have tried various import settings,but it doesn't work.I have searched on google,but no solution that I have found worked for me.Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find your image in your Assets-folder and check with Inspector what are the Max Size and Format -settings. If Max Size is smaller than the original image, it will be scaled down. In addition compression lowers quality but requires less space. It is also possible to use different settings for different platforms so that is probably the reason why they look fine on Windows. If you still have problems could you please give more information such as what kind of image are you importing and what import settings have you tried.

**EDIT** : In addition check that on the iPhone settings -tab "Override for iPhone" is not checked. Also you could try to make your texture size [power-of-two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two) for [optimization](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26187/why-are-textures-always-square-powers-of-two-what-if-they-arent). Sprites can not be generated for non-square textures in RGBA Compressed PVRTC 4 bits format.

[image: format and max size]

Comment: hi,I have added more details as an answer of the post.I am stuck on this issue.Any further suggestion please...